# Select com duas colunas retornando vazio

Tags: android, sqlite, join

Em uma aplicação mobile (Android), estou com duas tabelas. Uma tabela de login (usuário e senha) e uma outra de (cadastro simples). O APP tem uma tela de registro, se o usuário não tiver conta ele cria no momento e prossegue. Se esse usuário fizer um cadastro e popular a tabela de (cadastro simples) e um outro usuário que não tem conta, criar uma conta e acessar, ele vai acessar os dados do primeiro usuário.
Tentei rodar `INNER JOIN` porém o resultado (select) retorna vazio. Se eu rodar sem o `inner join (select * from tabela)` ele retorna os dados normalmente.

```
public class PessoaDao extends SQLiteOpenHelper {   
    private static final String NOME_BANCO = "TrainingBD";
    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABELA = "pessoa";

    private static final String ID = "_id";
    private static final String NOME = "nome";
    private static final String IDADE = "idade";
    private static final String CELULAR = "celular";
    private static final String DATACADASTRO = "dataCadastro";
    private static final String TIPOTREINO = "tipoTreino";
    private static final String PESO = "peso";
    private static final String ALTURA = "altura";
    private static final String OBSERVACAO = "observacao";
    private static final String USUARIOAUTENTICADO = "usuarioautenticado";

    private static final String TAG = PessoaDao.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String TABELAUSUARIO = "users";
    private static final String USERS_ID = "_id";
    private static final String USERS_LOGIN = "login";
    private static final String USERS_SENHA = "senha";

    public PessoaDao(Context context) {
        super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //tabela pessoas (formulario de cadastro)
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+TABELA+" (" +
                ""+ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                ""+NOME+" TEXT, "+
                ""+IDADE+" INTEGER, "+
                ""+CELULAR+" TEXT, "+
                ""+DATACADASTRO+" TEXT, "+
                ""+TIPOTREINO+" TEXT, "+
                ""+PESO+" TEXT, "+
                ""+ALTURA+" TEXT, "+
                ""+OBSERVACAO+" TEXT, "+
                ""+USUARIOAUTENTICADO+", INTEGER," +
                " FOREIGN KEY ("+USUARIOAUTENTICADO+") REFERENCES "+TABELAUSUARIO+"("+USERS_LOGIN+"));";

        db.execSQL(sql);

        String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABELAUSUARIO + "("
                + USERS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + USERS_LOGIN + " TEXT,"
                + USERS_SENHA + " TEXT);";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
    }

    //select para chamar os dados que estão no banco
    public ArrayList<Pessoa> selectAllPessoa(){
        String colunas = "SELECT * FROM " + TABELA + "," + TABELAUSUARIO + " WHERE " + TABELAUSUARIO + "." + USERS_LOGIN + " = " + TABELA + "." + USUARIOAUTENTICADO;

        //SE EU USAR ESSE MODO ELE RETORNO NORMALMENTE
        //OS DADOS JA CADASTRADOS
        //String colunas =  " Select * from " + TABELA  ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(colunas, null);

        ArrayList<Pessoa> listPessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

                pessoa.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                pessoa.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
                pessoa.setIdade(cursor.getString(2));
                pessoa.setCelular(cursor.getString(3));
                pessoa.setDataCadastro(cursor.getString(4));
                pessoa.setTipoTreino(cursor.getString(5));
                pessoa.setPeso(cursor.getString(6));
                pessoa.setAltura(cursor.getString(7));
                pessoa.setObservacao(cursor.getString(8));
                pessoa.setUsuarioautenticado(cursor.getString(9));

                listPessoa.add(pessoa);
            }
        cursor.close();
        return listPessoa;
    }
}
```

---

Sim, quando o usuário logar no app ele só mostrará o que ele adicionou ou o que editar na ListView.

Não era para funcionar se eu colocasse essa linha de código que você postou no meu método que já faz a busca

//select para chamar os dados que estão no banco
    public ArrayList selectAllPessoa(){

```
   String colunas = "SELECT * FROM " + TABELA + " WHERE " + USERS_ID + "=" + ID;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(colunas, null);

    ArrayList<Pessoa> listPessoa = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();

            pessoa.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            pessoa.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
            pessoa.setIdade(cursor.getString(2));
            pessoa.setCelular(cursor.getString(3));
            pessoa.setDataCadastro(cursor.getString(4));
            pessoa.setTipoTreino(cursor.getString(5));
            pessoa.setPeso(cursor.getString(6));
            pessoa.setAltura(cursor.getString(7));
            pessoa.setObservacao(cursor.getString(8));
            pessoa.setUsuarioautenticado(cursor.getInt(9));

            listPessoa.add(pessoa);

        }
    cursor.close();
    return listPessoa;
}
```

Esse outro trecho do código é onde eu populo a ListView, chamando o ArraylistPessoa onde já tem o Select modificado, porém aparece a ListView vazia.

public void preencheLista(){

```
    PessoaDao pessoaDao = new PessoaDao(CadastroActivity.this);
    arrayListPessoa = pessoaDao.selectAllPessoa();

    if(listView != null){
        arrayAdapterPessoa = new ArrayAdapter<Pessoa>(CadastroActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayListPessoa);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterPessoa);
    }
    pessoaDao.close();
}
```

---

habilitando FK

```
@Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()){
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }

    }
```

E já troquei o campo TEXT por INTEGER na FK que estava incorreto na hora de criar a Table.

```
"" + ID_USUARIO + ", INTEGER, " +
                    " FOREIGN KEY (" + ID_USUARIO + ") REFERENCES " + TABELAUSUARIO + "(" + USERS_ID + "));";
```

Porém surgiu esse erro que quando vou salvar os dados rodnado o app. 
Estou procurando saber inclusive

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ola,
voce que retornar os dados apenas do usuário logado certo? não vejo necessidade de fazer join....

voce ja tem o metodo que retorna todas as pessoas e teoricamente voce ja tem os dados do usuario autenticado, entao crie um metodo que retorne apenas a pessoa onde o id bate com o usuário logado, algo como

```
public Pessoa pegaPessoa(string id){

    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABELA + " WHERE " + USERS_ID + "=" + id

//.....restante do codigo

}
```

Answer (score 0):

O relacionamento entre as tabelas aparenta ser 1:1 (ou a sua aplicação vai permitir que 2 usuários possuam o mesmo user de login?). Se for o caso de ser 1:1, por que criar 2 tabelas? Não estou vendo ganho algum nessa implementação (separar dados pessoais de dados de acesso). Poderia manter tudo numa tabela só e evitar joins desnecessários.

Relacionamentos 1:1 fazem mais sentido quando você tem uma aplicação que quer consumir dados da tabela de outra aplicação e você gostaria de acrescentar dados (colunas) extras que não existem na tabela original e a sua aplicação não tem gestão sobre ela, então a solução é criar uma nova tabela com as colunas necessárias na sua aplicação colocando uma chave estrangeira referenciando a tabela de origem.

Desculpe ter fugido do tópico original, mas foi so uma sugestão mesmo. Com relação à pergunta, o join provavelmente não funciona porque você está comparando um campo INTEGER com outro que é TEXT. Inclusive a própria FK que você criou deve dar problemas por conta disso se você habilitar as constraints no BD (No SQLITE elas não vem habilitadas por padrão, tem que habilitar manualmente na inicialização do banco).